# Python unzip file exclude a particular file

Tags: python, zip

I am using python zipfile built-in module.

I am able to unzip a file but I need to exclude just one file.

Is there  a way I can do that?
Since I am using exctractall() I am getting the excluded file too.

```
  with ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r') as zipObj:
        # Extract all the contents of zip file in current directory
        zipObj.extractall()
```

Comment: Don't use `extractall`? `extractall` is a convenience, you can just list the members and only extract the ones you want.

Comment: ohh, using it for first time, need to checkout members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing this, I think you need to have these steps.

1. List the target file list for "extracting"
2. Add "If" condition or regex for specifying the only file you want to extract

```py
    with ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r') as zipObj:
        # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
        listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
        # Iterate over the file names
        for fileName in listOfFileNames:
            #check the excluding file condition.
            if fileName is 'FILE_TO_BE_EXCLUDED.txt':
                continue
            zipObj.extract(fileName, 'path_for_extracting')
```

My reference was [here.](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-unzip-a-file-extract-single-multiple-or-all-files-from-a-zip-archive/)
Hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: @iDev I am happy to hear that. Hope you will have a good day & good coding!