Why is python's zipfile module only extracting one file?
I'm currently writing an updater for my python program. It downloads a zip file and then opens it with the zipfile module. I loop through all the files in the zip, and if the file is not called 'updater.exe', extract it to the current directory. However, the program stops after extracting one file. I've seen people having a similar problem, but the answer appears tobe use extractall, which I cannot do because I can't extract updater.exe since the file will be overwritten and that is the program that will be running to do this task. I do want everything else to be overwritten. I am also using wxpython for progress dialogs. Here's the code I use for opening the zip file and extracting it.
  with ZipFile('wotu.zip', 'r') as f:
    files=f.namelist()
    dlg=wx.ProgressDialog('Updating', 'Extracting files...', len(files))
    progress=0
    for file in files:
      if file != 'updater.exe':
        print(file)
        f.extract(file)
        progress+=1
        dlg.Update(progress)


the program stops after extracting one file What do you mean "stops"?  Do you mean the program finishes normally?  Do you mean the program freezes and does not respond at all?  Do you mean it crashes with an error?

By stops I mean it just terminates normally. It does not print any errors. It takes a few seconds to close the progress dialog for extracting files, but then it just closes.

I tried equivalent code with a zip file containing three files, and it printed all three filenames.

Are you sure you're using the right zip file?  This will look for wotu.zip in the current directory, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python script.

You can use this to display the actual current directory: import os; print(os.getcwd())

I am certain that it is findingthe zip file in the current directory. You can download the exact zip file I am using this for from https://nibblenerds.com/wotu/wotu.zip

When I run this code on that file, I get thousands of filenames as output.  Either you're using the wrong file, or else the problem is in some other part of the code that you did not show us.

What is the name of the first extracted file?

You say only one file is extracted -- what about the output from print(file)?  Do you also see only one filename printed?

The file that is getting extracted is api-ms-win-core-console-l1-2-0.dll. I can provide the code that downloads the file if necessary. I also only see that one filename printed. I'm wondering if it's trying to extract them all too fast.
Edit: I tried adding a sleep after it extracted, and am still getting the same result.

I did some more googling and found another question that says that what I did should work.My reference was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966387/python-unzip-file-exclude-a-particular-file

If you're only seeing one filename printed, then the problem must be elsewhere, in other code that you haven't shown us.  You can test this for yourself -- make a small script based on this code, but remove the file extraction and wx dialog calls, with print(file) as the ONLY thing in the loop.

After some research, I leanred that you can pass a list of files to the extractall function, so all I have to do is iterate through the list of files from namelist and pop the ones I don't want to extract. This is the code I used.
  with ZipFile('wotu.zip', 'r') as f:
files=f.namelist()
dlg=wx.ProgressDialog('Updating', 'Extracting files...', len(files))
progress=0
for file in range(len(files)):
  if files[file] == 'updater.exe':
    files.pop(file)
    break
f.extractall(members=files)

